# Sitecore SXA search error

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-sxa

We are working on a Siteocore 8.2 update 3 solution with SXA and WFFM modules included. Everything is fine on CM Server but we are facing issues with search on CD server. 
We've enabled  'SwitchMastertoweb' and configured CD SXA settings as per the instructions in the installation guide. But still we are facing this  issue.
Any clue?

```
16728 15:36:13 ERROR Call to resource failed with exception - Resource: https://<<sitename>>/sxa/search/facets?f=sxacategoryname&p=3&l=&sig=&q=pets&s={F33B91B9-DB55-4E81-84C1-71C99E612F9F}|{F33B91B9-DB55-4E81-84C1-71C99E612F9F};
16728 15:36:13 ERROR 

GET call failed - Endpoint: https://<site>/sxa/search/facets?f=sxacategoryname&p=3&l=&sig=&q=pets&s={F33B91B9-DB55-4E81-84C1-71C99E612F9F}|{F33B91B9-DB55-4E81-84C1-71C99E612F9F}; 

HttpStatusCode: (400) BadRequest; HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request; Error: 
Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Lucene.LuceneIndex. No matching constructor was found.;

24392 15:36:13 WARN  Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Lucene.LuceneIndex. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class. Parameter info: Count: 0
24392 15:36:13 WARN  Facets endpoint exception

Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException
Message: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Lucene.LuceneIndex. No matching constructor was found.

Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.GetContextIndex(IIndexable indexable, GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.Process(GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.GetContextIndexPipeline.Run(ICorePipeline pipeline, GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService.GetQuery(String query, String scope, String language, Coordinates center, String& indexName)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetFacets(String f, String q, String s, String l, String g, String sig)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very late answer and I believe that this problem is already gone in 1.6 and 1.7. In the older releases of SXA we've been patching a lot of Sitecore indexes - unnecessary.

The exception which I can see there `Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Lucene.LuceneIndex. No matching constructor was found.` is exactly telling this. There is a patch for the index which doesn't exist. The solution for such kinds of issues is to remove not needed patches for indexes which doesn't exist (you are not using them, they are in present on your Sitecore instance).

In SXA 1.7 we have just patched for `sitecore_master_index` and `sitecore_web_index`. There is also an option to use SXA specific indexes and not use Sitecore one at all.